# Using jQuery, I'd like to know when an event occurs in the body of Gmail's new email composition iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, gmail, google-chrome-extension

The specific area I'm trying to access is the **body** of the **New Email Composition** in **Gmail**.

More generally, this is the **< BODY >** of an **iframe**, within *another* **iframe**.

This is being used for a simple Chrome Extension that I'm trying to develop, so this might be asked, my manifest file has the proper setting for frames:

```
"all_frames":true
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmmm. No one has ventured an answer.

I am sure this will be roundly shouted down and I am eager to see the right way to do it.

```
$('.Ak').live('click',function(){
  $(this) //reference to the element
});
```

The class name is `Ak` for the compose textarea.

This is a pretty horrible kludge but it works and you can fix it latter if that is holding up progress on something else.

Also, you should take a look at the chrome extension "After The Deadline". The code is not super complex and he successfully hooks his spell checker into the GMail textarea.

---

I just found a blog from the creator of ATD where he describes his trials and tribulations dealing with frames and Chrome Extensions. That may actually be very helpful too even if you are not doing an extension.

http://blog.afterthedeadline.com/2010/05/14/how-to-jump-through-hoops-and-make-a-chrome-extension/

Comment: Ah, got to writing and didn't add that you can find the class name for that object by 'inspect element' in chrome.